# Can't links beans in Spring Boot. The layer of services and controllers REST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Good evening! I want to get a list of entities via REST. Below is my code.

Repository

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {}
```

Service interface

```
public interface CustomerService {
    Page<CustomerRsDto> getAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Implementation of service interface

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    private final CustomerService customerService;
    
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Page<CustomerRsDto> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<CustomerRsDto> rsCustomers = customerService.getAll(pageable);
        return rsCustomers;
    }
}
```

REST Controller

```
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/customers")
@Api(tags = "customers", value = "Customres")
public class CustomersController {
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping
    @ApiOperation(tags = "customers", value = "Get all")
    public Page<CustomerRsDto> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        if (isNull(customerService)) {
            System.out.println("Not linked bean?");
        }
        return customerService.getAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this code I get two errors from the compiler. This

```
WARN 8928 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl' defined in file [<My Patch>\service\impl\CustomerServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerServiceImpl': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

and this

```
ERROR 8928 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  customerServiceImpl defined in file [<My Patch>\service\impl\CustomerServiceImpl.class]
└─────┘

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I found a solution in another similar question, using the constructor and @Lazy annotation. Below is the modified code.

Implementation of service interface

```
@Service
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    public CustomerServiceImpl(@Lazy CustomerService customerService) {
        super();
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Page<CustomerRsDto> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<CustomerRsDto> rsCustomers = customerService.getAll(pageable);
        return rsCustomers;
    }
}
```

And I get a new error.

```
2020-11-11 17:59:29.826  INFO 1236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
Not linked bean?
2020-11-11 17:59:30.308 ERROR 1236 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at <My Package>.rest.CustomersController.getAll(CustomersController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks to everyone who replies to this post!

**Upd 1:**

Implementation of service interface

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Page<CustomerRsDto> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
        List<Customer> dbCustomers = customerRepository.findAll();
        List<CustomerRsDto> listCustomers = null;

        dbCustomers.forEach(dbCustomer -> {
            listCustomers.add(customerMapper.toRsDto(dbCustomer));
        });

        Page<CustomerRsDto> rsCustomers = new PageImpl<CustomerRsDto>(listCustomers);

        return rsCustomers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `CustomerServiceImpl` having a dependency on `CustomerService` does not seem right.
From the shared code snippets looks like `CustomerServiceImpl` is the only implementation of `CustomerService`, so it having a dependency on a bean of type `CustomerService` is not correct. That seems the reason it first complains of circular dependency in the logs.

It looks like the intention is,

1. to have a dependency on `CustomerRepository`
2. to construct `CustomerRsDto` instances in `CustomerServiceImpl` after retrieving `Customer` instances from `CustomerRepository`

The `CustomerServiceImpl` should change to have a dependency on `CustomerRepository`.

Comment: I naively assumed that getAll can call findAll thanks to the magic of the Spring Boot. 

Now I'm returning probably the right object. But it doesn't help. Before that I was also just trying to return null to getAll.

Comment: Changes to the code are marked in the question header.

Comment: @HtmlMan, I suggest reviewing the code. The updated code uses `listCustomers` which is assigned to `null`. The updated code should be throwing `NullPointerException` now when trying to add a `Customer`. The code also does a `findAll` on the `CustomerRepository` and this might be problematic if there are a large number of customers as it will try to fetch everything in memory. Spring provides good documentation so do refer spring.io/learn and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.2.11.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference.